# classic ASP/VBscript error (Invalid character)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am getting the following error when i load an ASP page that calls a stored procedure from SQL 2000 with a parameter used at the point of loading the ASP page.

have i made a schoolboy error? and how do i fix this?

error

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0408'
Invalid character
/simon/stock_test.asp, line 6
declare @serial varchar(255)
--------^
```

and the page is stock_test.asp?ID=980028001365274

```
<!--#include file="includes/functions_test.asp"-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<%
declare @serial varchar(255)
set @serial = Request.QueryString("ID")

Call OpenDB()
Call OpenRecordSet(stock, "Exec sp_report_simon_test @serial")
%>

<html lang="EN">

<head>
    <title>Stock</title>
</head>

<body>

<table id="test">

    <tr>
        <td><b>Make</b></td>
        <td><b>Model</b></td>
        <td><b>Serial</b></td>
    </tr>

<%DO WHILE NOT stock.EOF%>

    <tr>
        <td><%=stock.Fields("Make").value %></td>
        <td><%=stock.Fields("Model").value %></td>
        <td><%=stock.Fields("serial_number").value %></td>
    </tr>

<%
stock.MoveNext
LOOP
%>

</table>

<%
Call CloseRecordSet(stock)
Call CloseDB()
%>

</body>
</html>
```

functions file

```
<%
response.Charset="utf-8"
Session.lcid = 2057
Response.Buffer = False
Server.ScriptTimeout=200

Dim dbConn
Function OpenDB()
    Set dbConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    dbConn.Open "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=server_name; Database=db_name; UID=username; PWD=password; Option=4"
End Function

Function CloseDB()
    If ucase(TypeName(dbConn)) = "OBJECT" Then
        dbConn.Close
        Set dbConn = Nothing
    End If
End Function

Function OpenRecordSet(RecSet, SqlQuery)
    Set RecSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set RecSet = dbConn.Execute(SqlQuery)
End Function

Function CloseRecordSet(RecSet)
    RecSet.Close
    Set RecSet = Nothing
End Function

Function ProcessSql(Sql, Page)
    Call OpenDB()
        dbConn.Execute(Sql)
    Call CloseDB()
    If Len(Page) > 0 Then   
        Response.Redirect(Page)
    End If
End Function

Function Encode(DirtyText)
    Dim CleanText
    Cleantext = Server.HtmlEncode(DirtyText)
    CleanText = Replace(CleanText, "'", "''")
    CleanText = Replace(CleanText, vbCrLf, "<br>")
    Encode = CleanText
End Function

Function mySqlDate(rawDate)
    Dim dateString
    dateString = DatePart("yyyy", cdate(rawDate))
    dateString = dateString & "-" & DatePart("m", cdate(rawDate))
    dateString = dateString & "-" & DatePart("d", cdate(rawDate))
    mySqlDate = dateString
End Function

Function GetMonthName(monthId)
    Dim monthNames
    monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")
    GetMonthName = monthNames(monthId -1)
End Function

Function CheckQueryString(Qstring, QName, Page)
    If Not Len(QString) = 0 AND Len(QString) < 6 AND IsNumeric(QString) Then
        QName = QString
    Else
        Response.redirect(Page)
    End If
End Function
%>
```

Comment: `declare @serial varchar(255)` is SQL syntax. ASP does not understand SQL syntax.

Comment: Get rid of the `@`  that's not your only problem, `Call OpenRecordSet(stock, "Exec sp_report_simon_test @serial")` wont work either.

Comment: The first error is the variable declaration and assignment that should look more like `Dim serial` and  
`serial = Request.QueryString("ID")`  Post the `OpenRecordSet` function and I will try and help with that too.

Comment: thanks, i've added the functions file code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's commendable that you try to use SQL parameters, but they don't work this way in ASP. It should be self-evident that you cannot simply drop SQL into your ASP code.

Use a Command object instead.

```vb
Dim stock, serialVal

OpenDB()

serialVal = Request.QueryString("serial")
If serialVal = "" Then serialVal = vbNull

With Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set .ActiveConnection = dbConn
  .CommandText = "sp_report_simon_test"
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@serial", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, serialVal)
  Set stock = .Execute
End With
```

Docs:

- [MSDN: Command Object (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN: Parameters Collection (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675869(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [MSDN: CreateParameter Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677209(v=vs.85).aspx)

---

To be able to use constants like `adCmdStoredProc` directly in the VBScript code they must be made available by referencing their type library at the top of your ASP page.

For Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 and up, use version 6.1:

```
<!--metadata 
    type="TypeLib" 
    name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" 
    uuid="B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129"
    version="6.1"-->
```

For earlier versions (Windows XP/Windows Server 2003), use version 2.8:

```
<!--metadata 
    type="TypeLib" 
    name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" 
    uuid="2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C"
    version="2.8"-->
```

Comment: OK thanks @Tomalak, i've changed "@id" in your code to "@serial" as that is the name of the variable in the stored procedure.

when i try this though i get an another error though

`ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/simon/stock_test.asp, line 13`

Comment: The name is not really important, SQL Server only cares for parameter *order* in stored procedures. But it's good to be consistent, that's why you should rename your query string parameter to "Serial" as well.

Comment: ok great, i've changed the query string parameter to "serial" too.... still getting an error though when running it

`ADODB.Command error '800a0bb9'

Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

/simon/stock_test.asp, line 13`

Comment: The code runs for me. Also I have no idea what "Line 13" is.

Comment: thanks for the help @Tomalak, i have updated the original post with the new code so that you can see it.

Comment: My code creates the parameter as `adInteger`. Maybe your serial is not an integer. Try `adVarChar` instead.

Comment: i had already changed that to `adVarChar` as serial is `varchar(30)`.
still same error though.

Comment: I can only say that my code works. I've tested it on Windows 2003 and on Windows 7, with two different versions of IIS and two different versions of the ADO library, I've even created a stored procedure named `sp_report_simon_test`. It works.

Comment: running IIS6, windows 2003 here, with SQL server 2000

Comment: do i need to add `<!--metadata 
    type="TypeLib" 
    name="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" 
    uuid="B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129"
    version="6.1"-->` to the top of my page?

Comment: *Of course*, (I said so, didn't I?) For Win2k3 try the 2.8 version of the library, see modified answer for the typelib reference. You will need to create an IIS application for that, too (via IIS Manager, right-click the folder, Properties, "Directory" tab, Application name, Click "Create".).

Comment: ok i totally missed that originally. have added that to the page, but i now get a different error

`ADODB.Parameters error '800a0e7c'

Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided.

/simon/stock_test.asp, line 20`

all your help is very much appreciated

Comment: I cannot be your line-wise interactive debugging helper. I can only recommend the normal course of action that every developer does to track down a problem: Create a blank ASP file, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code (so you don't miss any errors caused by undefined variables) and then build the statements bit by bit. Understand each statement, be conscious about the parameter values you choose and observe which values break it and which values make it work. My code *definitely* works, you will find the spot where your's is off.

Comment: i do appreciate the help

Comment: problem solved.. the length of the varchar wasn't defined in the code.
it now works with `"@serial", adVarChar, adParamInput, 30, Request.QueryString("serial") _`

Comment: @Tomalak You've got more patience then me.

Comment: @Lankymart It's been a while since I wrote any ASP code, it could have been my error. Part of the patience stems from that fact. ;-)